# C++: creating .exe file from a .jar file or creating .jar launcher - .exe file

Tags: java, c++, jar, exe

It would like to know how to create - I mean C++ example - .exe file from .jar file?
Do not want to use Launch4j or similar. Just want to do it from scratch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Comment: I mean C++ working example, not the software.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115090/EXE-Launcher-for-Java-Desktop-Application). It looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <windows.h>


using namespace std;

string getAppName() {

    // Creates char array with maximum needed length
    char result[MAX_PATH];
    // Uses <windows.h> method to retrieve app name. Only Windows OS
    std::string(result, GetModuleFileName(NULL, result, MAX_PATH));

    char* token;
    string name, next = "";

    //Iterates until end of tokens of Name string, divided by char -> '\' and '.'
    //The only '.' in Filename must be that for ".exe" , error otherwise.
    token = strtok(result, "\\.");
    while (next != "exe") {
        name = next;
        token = strtok(NULL, "\\.");
        next.assign(token);
    }
    return name;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ifstream file; // file stream
    string value = "";
    string jar_name = "";
    string image_name = "splash.gif";
    file.open("run.ini");
    if (!file) { // file does not exist, so use standard name
        jar_name = getAppName();
        jar_name += ".jar";
    } else {
        do {
            file >> jar_name;
            file >> image_name;
        } while (!file.eof());
        file.close();
    }

    //Launch JAVAW command on "jar_name" file with "image_name" splash image
    string exec_command = "start javaw -splash:" + image_name + " -jar " + jar_name;
    system(exec_command.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#include   
void main(void)
{
system("Java < Filename>");

Save as call center.c
properties:compile->make as .exe
Take the exe file from tc/bin